# Custom.css errors encountered in Safari OS X

Tags: css, safari

My webapp was designed for Chrome and Firefox. The CSS elements the same on both. Now I am also trying to get it work on latest Safari OS X.

Quite a few CSS elements don't work on Safari. Like for example in my custom CSS

This line doesn't work:

```
body{border:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
background-color:#eff0ea;
opacity:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 0; 
position: relative;
}
```

Then this line doesn't work:

```
.service .service_step{ display:none;}
```

Then this

```
.span_2_of_2 {  width: 100%;} 
.span_1_of_2 {  width: 49.2%;}
```

Since I am not an UI developer I have no clue why this are not working. So kindly help.

Secondly is there a tool where I can put my CSS code and check what will NOT work on Safari?

Thank You

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Take a look in the developer console (https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/). Chances are your rules are being overridden by a more specific or later CSS rule, or your CSS file isn't loading at all due to a 404 or something similar. The rules you list in your post work fine in Safari.